# Plotting an awkward pandas multi index dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I have a very awkward dataframe that looks like this:

```
+----+------+-------+-------+--------+----+--------+
|    |      | hour1 | hour2 | hour 3 | …  | hour24 |
+----+------+-------+-------+--------+----+--------+
| id | date |       |       |        |    |        |
| 1  | 3    |     4 |     0 |     96 | 88 |     35 |
|    | 4    |    10 |     2 |     54 | 42 |     37 |
|    | 5    |     9 |    32 |      8 | 70 |     34 |
|    | 6    |    36 |    89 |     69 | 46 |     78 |
| 2  | 5    |    17 |    41 |     48 | 45 |     71 |
|    | 6    |    50 |    66 |     82 | 72 |     59 |
|    | 7    |    14 |    24 |     55 | 20 |     89 |
|    | 8    |    76 |    36 |     13 | 14 |     21 |
| 3  | 5    |    97 |    19 |     41 | 61 |     72 |
|    | 6    |    22 |     4 |     56 | 82 |     15 |
|    | 7    |    17 |    57 |     30 | 63 |     88 |
|    | 8    |    83 |    43 |     35 |  8 |      4 |
+----+------+-------+-------+--------+----+--------+
```

For each `id` there is a list of `dates` and for each `date` the hour columns represent that full day's worth of data broken out by hour for the full 24hrs.

What I would like to do is plot (using matplotlib) the full hourly data for each of the `ids`, but I can't think of a way to do this.  I was looking into the possibility of creating numpy matrices, but I'm not sure if that is the right path to go down.

Clarification:  Essentially, for each id I want to concatenate all the hourly data together in order and plot that. I already have the days in the proper order, so I imagine it's just a matter finding a way to put all of the hourly data for each id into one object

Any thoughts on how to best accomplish this?

Here is some sample data in csv format: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/e56364930ddb3d04dec6994904b05cc6/test1.csv

Comment: How do you want to plot that?  Are you saying you want to plot each row of your DataFrame as a separate line, with all such lines combined in a single graph?

Comment: @BrenBarn  Essentially, for each id I want to concatenate all the hourly data together in order and plot that.  I already have the days in the proper order, so I imagine it's just a matter finding a way to put all of the hourly data for each id into one object

Comment: Again, please say what you mean by "plot that".  Plot it *how*?  Bar plot?  Line plot?  What does each bar/line represent?  How are the bares/lines combined into a single graph, if at all?  Do you mean that, e.g., for id=1 you would have a line with 96 points (because it has four dates with 24 points each)?

Comment: @BrenBarn I would like to make a line plot and yes, your example is correct.  Each plot will have a number of points that is equal to the number of dates * 24

Comment: Are you saying you want all these lines on the same graph, or a separate graph for each?  What do you want the X axis to represent on such a plot?

Comment: @BrenBarn A separate line graph for each ID and the x axis would represent the days/hours - i'd really only need tick marks for the days

Comment: It would help if you could post sample data in a format that can easily be imported (e.g., a short sample of the data as CSV).

Comment: @BrenBarn got it, getting that now

Comment: @BrenBarn sample data is in the post now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
for groupID, data in d.groupby(level='id'):
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    ax = fig.gca()
    ax.plot(data.values.ravel())
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data))*24)
    ax.set_xticklabels(data.index.get_level_values('date'))
```

`ravel` is a numpy method that will string out multiple rows into one long 1D array.

Beware running this interactively on a large dataset, as it creates a separate plot for each line.  If you want to save the plots or the like, set a noninteractive matplotlib backend and use `savefig` to save each figure, then close it before creating the next one.

Answer (score 2):

It might also be of interest to stack the data frame so that you have the dates and times together in the same index. For example, doing

```
df = df.stack().unstack(0)
```

Will put the dates and times in the index and the id as the columns names. Calling `df.plot()` will give you a line plot for each time series on the same axes. So you could do it as

```
ax = df.stack().unstack(0).plot()
```

and format the axes either by passing arguments to the `plot` method or by calling methods on `ax`.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it solves the 'awkward shaped data frame' problem

Answer (score 2):

I am not totally happy with this solution but maybe it can serve as starting point. Since your data is cyclic, I chose a polar chart. Unfortunately, the resolution in the y direction is poor. Therefore, I zoomed manually into the plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
df_new = df.set_index(['id','date'])
n = len(df_new.columns)

# convert from hours to rad
angle = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,n)


# color palete to cycle through
n_data = len(df_new.T.columns)
color = plt.cm.Paired(np.linspace(0,1,n_data/2)) # divided by two since you have 'red', and 'blue'
from itertools import cycle
c_iter = cycle(color)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

# looping through the columns and manually select one category
for ind, i in enumerate(df_new.T.columns):
    if i[0] == 'red':
        ax.plot(angle,df_new.T[i].values,color=c_iter.next(),label=i,linewidth=2)


# set the labels
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 24, endpoint=False))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(24))

# make the legend
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.2,1.1))
plt.show()
```

Zoom 0:

[image]

Zoom 1:
[image]

Zoom 2:
[image]

Comment: This is quite a bit different than what I was looking for, but this is still really, really, really awesome.

Comment: watch out if you copy paste the code, I just removed the y-log-scale

Comment: I am curious, what does this data represent ?